# Image Border control wrap question

Tags: c#, wpf, image

in the following example, my border wraps around the image. The border does not wrap tightly around the image because I use DecodePixelWidth to keep the aspect ratio. Two sides end up with the border right up against the image, and the other two have gaps from the control. Is there a clean way to have the border wrap the image while keeping the aspect ratio instead of setting the Image stretch to fill.

```
BitmapImage bitmapIkon = new BitmapImage();
bitmapIkon.BeginInit();
bitmapIkon.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmapIkon.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;

bitmapIkon.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath);

bitmapIkon.DecodePixelWidth = decodePixelWidth;
bitmapIkon.EndInit();
iImage.MinWidth=width;
iImage.MinHeight=height;
iImage.Source = bitmapIkon;
```

```
<Border Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="borderImageData"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0">
    <Image Name="iImage" Stretch="Uniform" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Name="iImage" Text="Uniform" Margin="1" />
    <Border Name="borderImageData" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

So effectively, the Grid sizes to fit the Image plus a margin of 1. The Border then stretches to fill the Grid, and draws it's border on top of the image.

If you are going to be using this a lot, then you may want to wrap it in a custom control.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. I do have this in a User Control. I had to change it a little, probably affected some in main window grid as well. Here is what I ended up with, only slightly different.

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Name="iImage" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0" />
        <Border Background="Transparent" Name="borderImageData"     BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0,2,0,2" />
    </Grid>